# use HTML <video> tag if supported else use lightbox??? (script)

Tags: video, html, tags, lightbox

is it popular to have a page display video using the new HTML  tag (as long as its supported by the browser), else fallback to using a lightbox???  [ & maybe even have another fallback??]

i've never had to do anything like this so i don't know.  would appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Lightbox? Could you give an example?

Although it’s quite a lot of HTML, [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) looks like a great way to use HTML5 video, with fallbacks for virtually every other browser (including IE 6), whilst only encoding your video file twice (which, sadly, is the minimum for HTML5 video at the moment).

If you want to detect HTML5 video with JavaScript, [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/detect.html) has a great walkthrough.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the browser doesn't support video then you could fall back to an object tag, which could fall back further by containing an embed tag.

Whether you want to present the video in a lightbox-style pop-up is a separate question of presentation rather than technology. Any of the above could be shown in a lightbox.